# passing variable from flash to php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-2

I have a variable called: name and a variable called score.

I want to send them, on release, to the database on my localhost so i could display them on a page. How can i send the two variables and add them to the mysql DB ?

i'm using actions script 2.0

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From actionscript 2 you need to use `LoadVars`.

```
your_btn.onRelease = function() {
    lv = new LoadVars();
    lv.score = score;
    lv.name = name;
    lv.load("http://localhost/send.php", "POST");
    lv.onLoad = function(src:String) {
        if (src) {
            // OK. src contains the output of the PHP file.
            // i.e. what you "print" or "echo" from php.
            trace(src);
        } else {
            // Problem. Most probably there's an error if src is undefined.
        }
    };
};
```

From PHP, you can get them from the `$_POST` array, and add them to mysql using `mysqli`.

```
$score = $_POST['score'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

// See a tutorial on how to add them to database.
// You need to connect to MySQL, then do an INSERT query to your table.
```

[Mysqli Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), or search for some tutorial on MySQL and php, there are plenty of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters from Flash to PHP by using GET parameters in your URL.

Start by making URL in Flash like `http://www.your-site.org/page.php?name=John&age=21`.

Then access you GET parameters in PHP like `$name = $_GET["name"]; $age = $_GET["age"];`

Comment: You might be in a lot of trouble if you have some weird characters in your url.

Comment: Fixed that. You can also use POST method. It largely depends on the data you are transferring.

Comment: Agreed. Just to make it clear to the OP, in case he would have some troubles (spaces, special characters, ...).